# Can't connect Socket on Android App in Visual Studio Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, sockets, xamarin.android

I'm Creating and App that connects de phone to a device through sockets, so far so good, the problem is that on some devices, and I tested on a few differente brands and APIS, the socket doesn't connect. I've tried both sync and async connect, on the sync method the exception is the "Operation on non-blocking socket would block" error 10035. And with the async method I get a connection success on the SocketAsyncEventArgs but then it throws a connection timeout error if I try to send any data.

Following my sync method

```
private bool OpenSocket(String EnderecoIP, int Porta)
    {
        Dispositivo = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Dispositivo.ReceiveTimeout = TimeOut;
        Dispositivo.SendTimeout = TimeOut;      
        try
        {
            Dispositivo.Blocking = false; // setting this didn't work =(
            Dispositivo.Connect(EnderecoIP, Porta);
            return Dispositivo.Connected;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            return Dispositivo.Connected;
        }



    }
```

And the async method:

```
internal void OpenSocketAsync(String EnderecoIP, int Porta)
    {
        SocketAsyncEventArgs connectArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        Dispositivo = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        Dispositivo.ReceiveTimeout = TimeOut;
        Dispositivo.SendTimeout = TimeOut;

        connectArgs.UserToken = Dispositivo;
        connectArgs.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(EnderecoIP), porta);

        IPEndPoint remoto = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(EnderecoIP), porta);
        object teste = new object();
        Dispositivo.BeginConnect(remoto, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback1), teste);

        Dispositivo.ConnectAsync(connectArgs);

        SocketError errorCode = connectArgs.SocketError;
        if (errorCode != SocketError.Success)
        {
            throw new SocketException((Int32)errorCode);
        }
    }
    public static System.Threading.ManualResetEvent allDone = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);
    public static void ConnectCallback1(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        allDone.Set();
        Socket s = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        s.EndConnect(ar);
    }
```

Again, on all Samsung devices I tested the sync method works fine(I didnt test de async method because I dont need the data exchange to be async). And on Motorola Devices under API 24 it also works, on version over the 24(>=) the exception is thrown. And on all Asus devices tested I couldn't get it to work.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: ,According to your description, you mean that you have no issue in all Samsung devices when you use sync, but have some issue in other device?

Comment: Yes, when I try to use the synchronous method on other devices I get the error "Operation on non-blocking socket would block" error 10035

Comment: @Radael, On Samsung device, works fine, I guess that your code is correct, may your device settings block socket.

Comment: Yes, I've even rooted a motorola phone to check that, but still got the error

Comment: ,Anything update?

Comment: After all this time, I made a new virtual machine from scratch installed everything again, newer versions of everything and I still get some exceptions, but it is connecting, so its kind of working. thx all for the support.